# What kind of connector (and lamp type) is this?

Tags: electrical, light, bulb

[image: Broken lamp]
Hi, I need to find a replacement (possibly LED) for this broken lamp, can someone tell me the soket type (and possibly suggest a drop-in replacement)

[EDIT]
I found that the original lamp was
OSRAM HQI-TS 250 W/NDL UVS
and it's is a HID

The connector is type Fc2 (Now I only need to find a LED, low wattage, replacement)

Comment: Looks like some type of halogen light. Is there an identifier on the socket itself somewhere? Might be on the backside. And if not, is this inside an appliance? And if so, does that have an identifying number?

Comment: Please [edit] in a clear picture of the socket. Also check all over the bulb for tiny faint writing.

Answer (score 6):

That is a metal halide bulb.

[image]

What sort of fixture was it in?

If you want to replace with LED, you'll need to also remove the ballast and ignitor that convert the input power into something the MH arc lamp can use.  The specs of the ballast will tell you more about the input voltage, which you will need to know to spec your LED.

You probably won't find a like-for-like LED replacement for that bulb because the bulb is only part of the system.  Even the drop-in LED replacements for the more popular HID applications that say they can be used without changing the ballast, etc, are dodgy.

In situations like this, I've found that if you are absolutely set on going with LED, it is usually cheaper to replace the whole fixture than to try and retrofit.  That said, HID is at least more efficient than incandescent or halogen so you're not at the bottom of the barrel even if you just replace with a new HID capsule.

Answer (score 4):

### Replace the whole fixture

The existing fixture is unsuitable for two reasons.

You aren't going to beat the efficiency of HID/metal halide.  They were popular precisely because they are so efficient, beating early LEDs and LEDs are only recently catching up.  If you can figure out the actual wattage of that bulb, you're going to need an LED nearly that *actual wattage* to have a comparable amount of light.

So first, that's gonna be a really big LED.  It will not physically fit in that enclosure.

Second, that enclosure is designed to hoard and conserve the heat generated by the HID light, because the HID light needs that heat to work.  *That is the exact opposite of what LEDs require* - they must be kept **cool**, with efficient heat **removal**.  So the fixture is totally unsuitable for any LED larger than about 2 watts lol.

Sell the fixture on Craigslist.  People who do indoor horticulture *love* HID lighting because it is all the right wavelengths.

Wait. So why would you want to replace it?  Because LED fixtures are better aimed.  Old lights want to light a 360 degree sphere.  LEDs light a 140-160 degree wedge natively, or narrower than that with some optics.  Thus you can put the light exactly where you want, and avoid wasting money on skyglow and lighting up people's bedroom windows. Thus you actually can reduce your watts.

Answer (score 2):

I would agree that it's a halogen of some sort.

The most important parts of the halogen are:

- the connectors at the end

  - which we can't completely see, but you can
- the length

  - which you can measure from the socket it came out of
- the max wattage
- which should be listed on the light somewhere

At this point, it's probably up to you to figure these items out since we don't have physical access to the lamp to find them for you.

Also note that the bulb type is also probably listed on the lamp itself, probably very close to the maximum wattage listing.

Comment: Also, if this is from inside an oven, you may need a special, more heat resistant kind.

Comment: Fair point, @MiG, but halogens tend to like heat (they produce enough of it!). The plastic in the mounts may need to be designed to withstand higher temps, though.

Comment: Exactly that :)

Comment: Beware also of low-voltage halogen bulbs - lamps with transformers were popular for a time, so you might have a line-voltage lamp with a 12V bulb in it you'd find at an auto parts store. The terminals on this bulb do **not** look like the typical T3-R7S line voltage linear bulb ceramic terminals.